# With gitlab omnibus changes not showing up on filesystem but they are showing up in the web interface

Tags: gitlab

I have pushed some changes to a repository that has a post-receive hook which rsyncs to another server. I reload the page, but my changes are not showing up. After some investigation, I checked the repo directory in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/gitlab-satellites` and noticed the changes are not there. I modified the style.css again, added `.iamtestingthis { }`, did a recursive grep for iamtestingthis and it returned nothing. The odd thing, when I look at the files in the Gitlab interface, I see the changes are there, but they are nowhere to be found on the server's filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a repositories directory under /var/opt/gitlab/git-data other than the satellites.

That is where you will find your git repositories. The satellites are used for merge requests, and other git work that gitlab might want to push to your repo. (And they can easily be blown away and remade when things go wrong)